# Get header data from a request response in swift

Tags: swift, api, rest, http-headers

I want to get X-Dem-Auth in a header request with swift to stock that in my app.

See the response :

```
headers {
    "Content-Length" = 95;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Date = "Fri, 15 Apr 2016 08:01:58 GMT";
        Server = "Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)";
        "X-Dem-Auth" = null;
        "X-Powered-By" = Express;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the response is type of `NSHTTPURLResponse` you can get header from `response.allHeaderFields`

As apple documentation says :

> A dictionary containing all the HTTP header fields received as part of the server’s response. By examining this dictionary clients can see the “raw” header information returned by the HTTP server.
>
> The keys in this dictionary are the header field names, as received from the server. See RFC 2616 for a list of commonly used HTTP header fields.

So to get for example a X-Dem-Auth in response header you can access it in that way :

```
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
     if let xDemAuth = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["X-Dem-Auth"] as? String {
        // use X-Dem-Auth here
     }
}
```

***UPDATE***

Updated due to comment from Evan R

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
     if let xDemAuth = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["X-Dem-Auth"] as? String {
        // use X-Dem-Auth here
     }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have an error : Value of type 'NSURLResponse?' has no member 'allHeaderFields'

Comment: Are you using Alafomofire?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it :) If it wouldn't work please provide you code in which you get response.

Comment: It would be nice if you mark this question as solved by my answer :)

Comment: It's now called `HTTPURLResponse` and not `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

Answer (score 3):

Update for iOS 13 and above.

I suggest if the response is of type HTTPURLResponse and you want get to a specific header value only. Then below is a better approach.

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
     if let xDemAuth = httpResponse.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Dem-Auth") as? String {
        // use X-Dem-Auth here
     }
}
```