# if conditions in the swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was going through this code snippet from one of the question in stackoverflow: [Get header data from a request response in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641700/get-header-data-from-a-request-response-in-swift/36641807)

there the author of the snippet have done something like this

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
     if let xDemAuth = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["X-Dem-Auth"] as? String {
        // use X-Dem-Auth here
     }
}
```

I have also seen code where there are if conditions which looks like this

```
if userInfoResponse as? HTTPURLResponse != nil {
```

I went to swift docs to see if there is any reference to such condition: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html but I wasn't able to found any reference of as. I asl went through this doc (https://www.programiz.com/swift-programming/if-else-statement)

Swift docs only gives this description

```
The else clause of an if statement can contain another if statement to test more than one condition. An if statement chained together in this way has the following form:

    if condition 1 {
        statements to execute if condition 1 is true
    } else if condition 2 {
        statements to execute if condition 2 is true
    } else {
        statements to execute if both conditions are false
    }

The value of any condition in an if statement must be of type Bool or a type bridged to Bool. The condition can also be an optional binding declaration, as discussed in Optional Binding.
```

Which looks similar to if condition in javascript. Can someone explain me the above if else condition? Like what is `as?` in the above condition?

Comment: It's all there in the doc: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

Comment: ... and in particular the [Downcasting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID341) section on that page.

Comment: @MartinR, how do you get the URL directly to a section? Is there a way besides looking at the page’s HTML source?

Comment: @vacawama There is a popup menu at the top of the page (perhaps not in the mobile view).

Comment: @MartinR, Fantastic! It was clearly hiding in my blind spot. I’ve never noticed it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simplified with an example

```
let df:Any = 123

if let res = df as? String {
    print(res)
}
else { 
    print("no") // prints
}
```

and

```
if let res = df as? Int {
    print(res)  // prints 
}
else { 
    print("no")
}
```

BTw , your code could be

```
if let res =  userInfoResponse as? HTTPURLResponse {
   // use res
}
```

or

```
if let _ =  userInfoResponse as? HTTPURLResponse {

}
```

or

```
if userInfoResponse is HTTPURLResponse {

}
```

instead of

```
if userInfoResponse as? HTTPURLResponse != nil {
```

Answer (score 1):

The `as` keyword is a typecast operator. `x as? T` returns an optional `T` which is `x` cast as `T` if `x` is a `T` (or subclass) or `nil` if `x` is not a `T`. So

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
```

attempts to cast `response` as an `HTTPURLResponse` and binds `httpResponse` to it if successful.

```
if userInfoResponse as? HTTPURLResponse != nil
```

is just as test to see if `userInfoResponse` is an `HTTPURLResponse`. Whoever wrote it is not aware of the `is` keyword because it is equivalent to

```
if userInfoResponse is HTTPURLResponse
```

> I went to swift docs to see if there is any reference to such condition

You were just looking in the wrong place.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_type-casting-operator

Answer (score 0):

It tries to typecast the response received as HTTPURLResponse object. If the it is successfully parsed and its value is not null, your if condition becomes true and within that context, httpResponse constant becomes available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here `HTTPURLResponse` is the class. `response as? HTTPURLResponse` caste the `response` as a `HTTPURLResponse`. `response` is the object of the `HTTPURLResponse` class. If `response` will not be object or reference of the `HTTPURLResponse` class then `response as? HTTPURLResponse` this statement will result **`nil`**. `if let` (optional binding) checks that object is nil or not.

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
     print("response is not nil")
}
```

Above code will execute print statement if `httpResponse` aka `response` is not `nil`.