# how to split http response in Swift using boundary from Content-Type header param

Tags: swift, http, multipart

This is the verbose output using curl to request the server

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 55254 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:55254
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: WDA MJPEG Server
< Connection: close
< Max-Age: 0
< Expires: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--BoundaryString
<
```

I am new to Swift and have some difficulties in finding libraries to read the http response and split it using the boundary param found in Content-Type, I know in golang, we can use the multipart.Reader

```
multipartReader := multipart.NewReader(resp.Body, boundary)
multipartReader.NextPart()
```

how do I achieve the same in swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641700/get-header-data-from-a-request-response-in-swift/36641807 check this link

Comment: I guess that https://github.com/vapor/multipart-kit does the job, else it's quite some job to do. Retrieve the boundary in the header fields, then parse the `Data` (as `Data`), `httpBody` won't be parsable into `String` with `utf8` (surely a beginner mistake you'll want to do).

Comment: @Larme My scenario is the server serves data as long as the client doesn't leave, so I can't get all response payload, which this library requires...